# Ubuntu 11.10 not displaying any open applications, when running in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I have managed to get 3D acceleration to work when running Ubuntu 11,10 in virtualbox, however, when Ubuntu loads the unity display, any application I launch seems to be hidden.

The open apps are running, but not being displayed.

All works fine when in 2D, so it is something to do with the 3D acceleration.

Wondered if anyone had the same issue...

- Host: OS x Lion
- Guest: Ubuntu 11.10

When I resize the virtualbox window, the applications flashes on to the screen, but then disappears again.

When I right click, I can create a document, the icon is shown on the desktop, but when I open it, again it is there but does not display.

#### Additional:

- Virtualbox settings:

  - Video Memory: 128MB
  - 3D Acceleration Enabled
  - Base Memory 1512MB
  - 1CPU (uncapped)
  - VirtualBox Version 4.1.8 r75467
- Installed on Guest:

  - xserver-xorg-video-intel
  - xserver-xorg-video-vmware
  - VIRTUALBOX-GUEST-DKMS
  - VIRTUALBOX-GUEST-UTILS
  - VIRTUALBOX-GUEST-X11
    -VIRTUALBOX-OSE-GUEST-X11
  - ALL VERSIONS 4.1.2-DSFG-1UBUNTU1
- Host info:

  - Processor  2.53 GHz Intel Core i5
  - Memory  8 GB 1067 MHz DDR3
  - Graphics  NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M 512 MB
  - Software  Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2 (11C74)
  - Extension Pack: Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.1.8-75467.vbox-extpack

Unity 3D displays ok, but when any program is opened it is not displayed, however is running, as though it is behind the desktop. If i resize the virtualbox window the running program flashes on the screen and then disappears again

If I right click on the desktop after opening a program, eg Nautilus, the nautilus right click menu appears. So the program is there, and operational, but is not being displayed.

Has anyone got Unity working in Virtualbox or VMWare Fusion, if so what versions of Virtual**** software?

Reported bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/909534

Comment: can you provide your virtualbox setting?

Comment: Video Memory: 128MB, 3D Acceleration Enabled, Base Memory 1512MB, 1CPU (uncapped)

Comment: VirtualBox Version 4.1.8 r75467

Comment: On guest: xserver-xorg-video-intel and xserver-xorg-video-vmware

Comment: However, Guest sys info GRAPHICS: UNKNOWN

Comment: Installed on guest: VIRTUALBOX-GUEST-DKMS, VIRTUALBOX-GUEST-UTILS, VIRTUALBOX-GUEST-X11, VIRTUALBOX-OSE-GUEST-X11 ALL VERSIONS 4.1.2-DSFG-1UBUNTU1

Comment: How do I upgrade virtual guest additions? Thanks

Comment: When I select DEVICES/INSTALL GUEST ADDITIONS... nothing happens..

Comment: Added: Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.1.8-75467.vbox-extpack

Comment: still the same issue. Unity 3D displays ok, but when any program is opened it is not displayed, however is running, as though it is behind the desktop. If i resize the virtualbox window the running program flashes on the screen and then disappears again

Comment: I wonder if the desktop is not refreshing...

Comment: @pst007x - can you confirm that you have installed the MACOS NVidia proprietary driver - if you have, what is the version of the driver?

Comment: Checked drivers, the xserver MAC drivers are installed from the repo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported the bug here: Reported bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/909534

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to be using multiple monitors? If so, I wonder if Unity thinks you have a desktop that's larger than your physical display and then placing apps off-screen.

Try this:

- In VirtualBox, with the VM powered off, go to Settings > Displays > Monitor Count. Make sure it's 1.
- Once powered on, select the power logo in the upper right of the Unity menu bar. Select Displays. Make sure it also shows only one monitor.

This is a wild guess (the bounty made me do it!).

Comment: Only one monitor...